# Polymer and Bootstrap 4

Tags: polymer, bootstrap-4

I wanted to create some custom elements using my favo library 'polymer'. However, when I want to use some Bootstrap 4 components, like the navbar, things do not seem to work anymore, which I understand because the event binding and handling implemented by Bootstrap is based on jQuery and does not take Shadow Dom (therefore isolation) in consideration.

Is there anyone who has used a Bootstrap 4 component inside of a Polymer component succesfully. So I mean component not css classes :-).

Just curious, 
John.

Comment: The joys of polymer, there's a component for that https://www.webcomponents.org/element/LostInBrittany/granite-bootstrap